# Can't access service exposed by ingress in the Minikube

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I was testing deployment .NET services to kubernetes using HELM charts and faced with an issue of my service not being accessible using ingress name but only with `minikube tunnel`.

I tried to deploy my simple .NET web api to minikube with ingress not to bake calls to ip addresses but faced with an issue that I cannot access my service via ingress. So I've tried [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) tutorial and it does not word also: [here is step by step recreation of their guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVAgP.png).
I use:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Minikube 1.30.1
```

The only possible way to access service is to start `minikube tunnel` and change ip in `/etc/hosts` to 127.0.0.1 which does not fit my needs.
I've seen that direct ingress acccess does not work on Windows, but I'm using Linux and it does not work for me also. Need help with fixing that.